# How to find an element by classname in another cell in a table row?

Tags: jquery

From the change event of a textbox in a td, I want to find a div whose classname = 'licenseStatus' in another cell within the row in which the textbox resides but can't seem to figure it out...

```
$('#gridRequestedApps .xxxAppName').change(function() {
   var licenseOutputCell = $(this).parent('tr').find(".licenseStatus");
   alert(licenseOutputCell.text());    // is an empty string
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `parents()` function:

```
$("#gridRequestedApps .xxxAppName").change
(
  function()
  {
    var licenseOutputCell = $(this)
                              .parents("tr:first")
                              .find("div.licenseStatus");
    alert(licenseOutputCell.text());
  }
);
```

`parents("tr:first")` works because you're selecting the first TR ancestor element, and not a direct parent which is what `parent()` does.